# Cassandra driver querying with multiple keys

Tags: c++, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm trying to query cassandra from a c++ application, and return the values for a set of keys. I am using the datastax driver described here: http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/api/

The cassandra query string is something like this:

```
SELECT value from my_table WHERE key IN (?);
```

If I prepare a separate query string for each number of parameters, I can use `cass_statement_bind_string_n` , but is there a way to use one string regardless of the number of keys I wish to query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things here:

1. the syntax `IN (?)` means that you are always asking only for one item - your list has only one entry;
2. if you want to query multiple items, you need to change syntax to `IN ?` and bind it using [ass_statement_bind_collection_by_name](http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/api/struct.CassStatement/#function-cass_statement_bind_collection_by_name) to the value has `LIST` type. [See doc on how you can create collection types](http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/basics/data_types/);
3. Using `IN` for query on partition key is really anti-pattern - it adds load to the node that is performing the query, and makes your queries slower as coordinating node will need to send requests to other nodes, and wait for results, collect them, and send back. It's will be faster if you issue separate requests for each partition key, and collect answer in your application.